# Can't call a function in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I created this function in my controller

```
func addMarker(place:EClass) {

    guard let coordinates = place.location  else {
        return
    }

    self.destination = coordinates
    // clear current marker
    marker.map = nil

    marker.position = coordinates
    marker.title = place.name
    marker.map = mapView
    mapView.selectedMarker = marker

    }
}
```

and now i'm trying to call it in my viewDidLoad because i want to add some markers in my mapView

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(categories as Any)

        guard let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser else {
            return
        }



        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self

        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm"
        print(dateFormatter.string(from: NSDate() as Date))


         mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
         locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()


         //HERE 
         let srt = sortedArray
         for category in categories! {
            addMarker(place: srt)
        }



}
```

but i'm getting the error "Use of unresolved identifier 'addMarker'" , why? How can i fix it?

Comment: by looking at the function you have an extra close curly brace

Comment: is "srt" variable in your code EClass type ? seems like sortedArray is array so it must be [EClass] ?

Comment: Closed with typography mistake

Comment: @Krunal I mean that func addMarker(place:[EClass]) { ... } if sortedArray is array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `addMarker` has an extra bracket.

```
 func addMarker(place:EClass) {

    guard let coordinates = place.location  else {
        return
    }

    self.destination = coordinates
    // clear current marker
    marker.map = nil

    marker.position = coordinates
    marker.title = place.name
    marker.map = mapView
    mapView.selectedMarker = marker

 }
```

Comment: instead of answering  such as question  you should flag as close

Comment: It's a perfectly valid question, it has happened to everyone at least once.

Comment: right! I have not notice that, thank you

Comment: did the OP read my comments lol :(

Comment: thank you also to you @Lamar i read late your comment

Comment: @AlejandroIván read the help page and especially the extract of it under this question as the close reason. Typographical errors might have happened to everyone at least once, but solving an issue regarding a typographical error is not useful at all for future readers, hence they are considered off-topic

Comment: @DávidPásztor you're right. Maybe the parser/compiler should need to be more specific and say `Uneven number of parenthesis` instead of `Use of unresolved identifier 'addMarker'`.